# Talkback announcing "Tap with 3 fingers to view Talkback Menu" before focusing back to the desired button

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

This is occurring because I added a delay to a toast being focused on due to other things occurring in the given screen. I also added a AccessibilityManager.interupt() which I thought would fix the issue but it is still present. Is it possible to remove this?

Comment: Focusing a toast seems weird. “Because alerts are intended to provide important and potentially time-sensitive information without interfering with the user's ability to continue working, it is crucial they do not affect keyboard focus.” I think you should simply not do this, which will fix your issue. Setting focus somewhere else after a timeout sounds particularly disorienting for keyboard users. See the [Alert Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/alert/) for better solutions.

Comment: Hey so the reason I am attempting to focus on it is cause it gets cut off before finishing. Attempting to lengthen the toast did not fix the issue. Not doing this leads to the full toast not being read so I am not sure what I can do to fix this. i'll try removing the focus but keeping the delay